# asp.net web form Form Authentication - Error 401.2, favor su ayuda

Tags: c#, asp.net, autenticación, web.config

tengo un proyecto web asp.net wen form, en emi web config tengo lo siguiente:
[image: Web.Config donde se muestra configuración de autenticación]

Como ven algo bastante simple, pero a la hora de hacer correr el proyecto me lanza el siguiente error:

[image: Error al hacer correr programa]

Las propiedades del proyecto son:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Le di vueltas por todo lado y no logro identificar por que tengo el problema, alguien me puede colaborar por favor.

Les agradezco de antemano, saludos cordiales a todos.

Answer (score 0):

Pueden ser muchas razones, pero la más común es que la autenticacion anónima está deshabilitada. En las Propiedades de tu Aplicación verifica que esté Enabled.
Dale click al nombre de tu aplicacion en el Solution Explorer y presiona F4 para ver las propiedades:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: reekeecast gracias por tu respuesta, pero esta como me indicas, también adicione ese detalle en la pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

Es un tema de configuración, en ningún momento estás autorizando el acceso tu `Login.apx` de forma anónima. Estás restringiendo anónimos a todos tus formularios `<deny users="?"/>`.

Tendrías que usar:

```
<configuration>

<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms"/>

    <authorization> 
        <deny users="?"/>  // Restringir anónimos
    </authorization>

</system.web>

<location path="Login.aspx"> // Debería estar habilitada para todos
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*"/> // Permitir a todos acceder
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>

</configuration>
```

*Cuando formules una pregunta usa texto y no imágenes.*

Comment: Gracias Davlio, adicioné el código que me sugeriste y el problema persiste de la misma manera.

Comment: Alguien que tenga la respuesta al problema?